# Using form input to change structure of a pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create something that uses Google charts found here (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_charts.asp). However I am wanting to get input using some sort of HTML form element and change the pie chart based on the input. 
For example, the w3schools example has the chart initially look like,

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
['Work', 18],
['Friends', 2],
['Eat', 2],
['TV', 3],
['Gym', 2],
['Sleep', 7]
]);
```

but what I am wondering is how to let a user dictate what and how many "tasks" exist and how many hours is spent on each task. I'd imagine that I would want to use HTML forms for the input, but I am unsure of how to take the input from the form and use it as the new values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AngularJs. Bind the values which you want to make parametric to Angular variables. Also Bind these variables to input fields. So changing these inputs is expected to change pie chart.

Comment: I did not think about using AngularJs so thanks and I will try that. However is it possible to use jQuery in a potentially similar way?

Comment: Yes it seems possible in my opinion.

Comment: Sure! I went ahead and did it. But I'm still having trouble changing the elements. Do you have any links by chance that might help point me in the right direction? Really I'm just wanting to somehow let the user enter in a task and the hours and then the pie chart shows up with the input or at the very least just set the hours and have the tasks stay how they are.

Comment: This link might be a good starting point: https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/pie/